# Proof of Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, svd

Could someone please explain why in [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart.E2.80.93Young.E2.80.93Mirsky_theorem) one says "*we know  that $\exists(k+1)$ dimension space* $(v_1,v_2, \dots, v_n)$" ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One needs to show that if $\mathrm{rank}(B)=k$, then $\|A-B\|_2\geq\|A-A_k\|_2$. This can be done as follows.

Since $\mathrm{rank}(B)=k$, $\dim\mathcal{N}(B)=n-k$ and from $$\dim\mathcal{N}(B)+\dim\mathcal{R}(V_{k+1})=n-k+k+1=n+1$$ (where $V_{k+1}=[v_1,\ldots,v_{k+1}]$ is the matrix of right singular vectors associated with the first $k+1$ singular values in the descending order), we have that there exists an
$$x\in\mathcal{N}(B)\cap\mathcal{R}(V_{k+1}), \quad \|x\|_2=1.$$
Hence
$$
\|A-B\|_2^2\geq\|(A-B)x\|_2^2=\|Ax\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\sigma_i^2|v_i^*x|^2\geq\sigma_{k+1}^2\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}|v_i^*x|^2=\sigma_{k+1}^2.
$$
From $\|A-A_k\|_2=\sigma_{k+1}$, one gets hence $\|A-B\|_2\geq\|A-A_k\|_2$. No contradiction required, Quite Easily Done.

---

**EDIT** An alternative proof, which works for both the spectral and Frobenius norms, is based on the Weyl's theorem for eigenvalues (or more precisely, its alternative for singular values): if $X$ and $Y$ are $m\times n$ ($m\geq n$) and (as above) the singular values are ordered in the descreasing order, we have
$$\tag{1}
\sigma_{i+j-1}(X+Y)\leq\sigma_i(X)+\sigma_j(Y) \quad\text{for $1\leq i,j\leq n, \; i+j-1\leq n$}
$$
(this follows from the variational characterization of eigen/singular values; see, e.g., Theorem 3.3.16 [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LeuNXB2bl5EC)).
If $B$ has rank $k$, $\sigma_{k+1}(B)=0$.
Setting $j=k+1$, $Y:=B$, and $X:=A-B$, in (1) gives
$$
\sigma_{i+k}(A)\leq\sigma_i(A-B) \quad \text{for $1\leq i\leq n-k$}.
$$
For the spectral norm, it is sufficient to take $i=1$. For the Frobenius norm, this gives
$$
\|A-B\|_F^2\geq\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\sigma_i^2(A-B)\geq\sum_{i=k+1}^n\sigma_i^2(A)
$$
with the equality attained, again, by $B=A_k$.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe i'm missing something, but what i don't understand is this: what has $V_{k+1}$ to do with everything else and how it is connected to rank(B).

Comment: @AlexGaspare I'm not sure I've understood the question. $V_{k+1}$ is formed from the first $k+1$ right (not left, sorry) singular vectors of $A$, that is, first $k+1$ columns of $V$ from the SVD $A=U\Sigma V^*$; truncating this SVD determines the optimal approximation $A_k$. It does not have much to do with the rank of $B$, except that it has a non-trivial intersection with the nullspace of $B$ by the dimensional argument (if the sum of the dimensions of two subspaces of an $n$-dimensional subspace is larger than $n$, they have non-trivial intersection).

Comment: i'm sorry to bring this up now, but why is squaring the norm needed again? And why does $||A−B||_2^2≥||(A−B)x||_2^2$ holds?

Comment: @AlexGaspare Squaring norms is not needed, it's there just to avoid typesetting square roots. The numbers are all non-negative so it does not matter. If $C$ is a matrix and $\|x\|_2=1$, then $\|Cx\|_2\leq\|C\|_2$ simply because $\|C\|_2=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Cx\|_2$ (so taking a particular $x$ in $\max$ is a lower bound for the $\max$).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: +1, but when you write $\|\cdot\|_2$, which norm are you referring to? As you say that $\|A\|_2=\sigma_\mathrm{max}$, I guess you are using the operator norm, but isn't Eckart-Young theorem (also?) true for Frobenius norm that is often denoted in exactly the same way $\|A\|_F = \|A\|_2=\left(\sum \sigma^2_k\right)^{1/2}$? How does the proof work in that case? The wiki article does start with Frobenius norm, but then somehow seems to switch to the operator norm.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Could you please tell me what you used to get $\|Ax\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\sigma_i^2|v_i^*x|^2$? I cannot understand the hidden passages... thanks!

Comment: @gosbi It's because $x\in\mathcal{R}(V_{k+1})$, so it can be written as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_{k+1}$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Then, I don't understand where $A$ is, as for what I have understood, $v_i^*x$ is just a way to write $x$. I tried to compute it explicitly, but I got quite a different result:
$$
\| A x \|_2 = (Ax)^*(Ax) = x^*V\Sigma^*U^*U\Sigma V^*x =
(V^*x)^*\Sigma^2(V^*x) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\sigma_i^2\mid v_i^* x\mid
$$
where the term in the sum is not squared, which makes a great difference in the following passage of the proof.

Comment: @gosbi The problem of the last equality is that you forgot that square.

Comment: @amoeba Sorry for the delay :-) I've added some details for the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Sorry but you can't write ‖−‖2=+1 at the end of the first proof :) It's a sum from k + 1 to n.

Comment: @Jill-JênnVie I'm not sure what you mean. The largest singular value of $A-A_k$ is $\sigma_{k+1}$ so its 2-norm is $\sigma_{k+1}$.

Comment: Hi. I'll appreciate if someone clarify my following doubt: Why $N(B) \cap R(V_{k}) = \{0\}$. What i am understanding, and it must be certainly correct (since this same proof is in one of Gilbert Strang's books), is that the argument in line 7 will *only* work for $V_{k+i}$  where i is a positive integer. But how can one be certain that for $V_{k-i}$ will not work. In other words, why would the inersection between $V_{k-i}$ and $mathcal{N}(B)$ equal {0} where 0 is the zero vector. Thank you

Comment: @Mangostino Nobody claims that $N(B)\cap R(V_k)=\{0\}$. What is true that *for any* $B$ of rank $k$, $N(B)\cap R(V_{k+1})\neq\{0\}$ which is the key for the proof. On the other hand, *there exist* $B$ of rank $k$ such that $N(B)\cap R(V_k)=\{0\}$ but there are also such matrices for which these intersections are nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks. Finally got that spine out from my toe.

Comment: why is ()∩(+1) ≠ {0}?

Comment: @rando If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional subspaces of space of dimension $n$, we have $\mathrm{dim}(V\cap W)=\mathrm{dim}(V)+\mathrm{dim}(W)-\mathrm{dim}(V+W)$. With $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n-k$, $\mathrm{dim}(W)=k+1$, and $\mathrm{dim}(V+W)\leq n$, we have $\mathrm{dim}(V\cap W)\geq (n-k)+(k+1)-n=1$, that is, $V\cap W$ is non-trivial.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly simplified version of the proof on wiki.

As shown there, $\left \| A - A_k \right \|_2 = \sigma_{k+1}$. Now, suppose $\exists \ B$ such that $\mathrm{rank}(B) \leq k$ and $\left \| A - B \right \|_2 < \left \| A - A_k \right \|_2$. Then, $\text{dim} (\mathrm{null}(B)) \geq n-k$. Let $w \in \mathrm{null}(B)$, then
\begin{equation}
\left \| A w \right \|_2 = \left \| (A - B)w \right \|_2 \leq \left \| A - B \right \|_2 \left \| w \right \|_2 < \sigma_{k+1} \left \| w \right \|_2
\end{equation}
Also, for any $v \in \mathrm{span}\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{k+1} \}$, $\left \| A v \right \|_2 \geq \sigma_{k+1} \left \| v \right \|_2$. But, 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{null}(B) \cap \mathrm{span}\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{k+1} \} \neq \{0\}
\end{equation}
So, $\exists$ a non-zero vector lying in both spaces. This'll lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain to me why $\left \| A - A_k \right \|_2 = \sigma_{k+1}$ ? I'll appreciate

Answer (score -2):

The original statement of Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem on wiki is based on Frobenius norm, but the proof is based on 2-norm. Though Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem holds for all norms invariant to orthogonal transforms, I think it is necessary to add a proof purely based on Frobenius norm since it is even easier to prove than that based on 2-norm.

The following proof is replicated from [these notes](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/5101/Low%20rank%20Approx.pdf).

Since $||M-X_k||_F = ||U\Sigma V^\intercal - X_k||_F = ||\Sigma - U^\intercal X_k V ||_F$, denoting $N = U^\intercal X_k V$, an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $k$, a direct calculation gives
\begin{equation}
  ||\Sigma-N||_F^2 = \sum_{i,j} |\Sigma_{i,j} - N_{i,j}|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^r |\sigma_i-N_{ii}|^2+\sum_{i>r}|N_{ii}|^2+\sum_{i\neq j} |N_{i,j}|^2
\end{equation}
which is minimal when all the non diagonal terms of $N$ equal to zero, and so are all  diagonal terms with $i > r$. Obviously, the minimum of the terms left is attained when $N_{ii} = \sigma_i$ for $i = 1,2,\cdots,k$ and all other $N_{ii}$ are zero.

Comment: I think this proof is incorrect. Since $\mathrm{rank}(N) \le k$, all the $N_{ij}$ are coupled with one another. So it does not follow that the minimum should be attained when $N_{ij}=0$ for $i\ne j$.