# Why $||U\Sigma V^\intercal - X_k||_F = ||\Sigma - U^\intercal X_k V ||_F$

Tags: svd

Here $U\Sigma V^\intercal $ is the svd decomposition of M.I know that U and V are othogonal but i dont know which property it is using.
This in reference to the post [Proof of Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759032/proof-of-eckart-young-mirsky-theorem) 
$$||M-X_k||_F = ||U\Sigma V^\intercal - X_k||_F = ||\Sigma - U^\intercal X_k V ||_F$$

Answer (score 1):

As @science said:

$$||U\Sigma V^\intercal - X_k||_F=||U(\Sigma- U^\intercal X_k V) V^\intercal ||_F$$

Now use the property of F-norm

$$||UAV^T||=\sqrt{\text{trace}((UAV^T)^T(UAT^T))}=\sqrt{\text{trace}(VA^TU^TUAV^T)}=\sqrt{\text{trace}(VA^TAV^T)}=\sqrt{\text{trace}(A^TAV^TV)}=\sqrt{\text{trace}(A^TA)}=||A||_F$$

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to see that

> $$ U\Sigma V^\intercal - X_k \iff (U\Sigma - X_kV)V^{\intercal} \iff U(\Sigma - U^{\intercal}X_kV)V^{\intercal}. $$

Comment: i am not getting why the first term is equivalent to the second term why $U\Sigma V^T - X_k \iff U\Sigma V^TV$

Comment: Just apply $V$ from the right as $ (U\Sigma V^\intercal - X_k)V  $.

Comment: that is what i am not getting how can i apply V then the two term is not equal.Is it because multiplying with V does not change the optimization problem ?

Comment: they have also stated that the frobenius norm is equal.I am not getting it is coming from which property of probenius norm.Is there any property of frobenius norm that it is orthogonal matrix invariant?

Comment: I'll ben with you..

Comment: sorry but i am not getting your comment.