# convex for two variables

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose we have the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{X,Y}~L=\min_{X,Y}~\|A-XY\|_2^2,$$
where $X\in R^{m\times n}$, $Y\in R^{n\times p}$ and $A\in R^{m\times p}$.
Could someone give me some hints on how to determine the convexity of the formulation of $L$. Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Can it be done like this- considering one of the variables as constant then the function will be a norm function of that variable. So the norm is a convex function.

Comment: The problem is **not** convex in joint $X$,$Y$ variables, only *biconvex*. It is the known [low rank approximation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation). The minimum is $\sigma_{n+1}^2$ ([Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759032/proof-of-eckart-young-mirsky-theorem))

Comment: As @A.G. correctly states, it is not convex. But unless you add other constraints (e.g., nonnegativity of $X$ and $Y$), it has an easy solution via the SVD; it's just the standard rank-$p$ approximation of $A$, with a minimum value of $\sigma_{p+1}(A)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $L(X,Y)=\|A-XY\|_2^2$ is not convex. To construct a counterexample, let's perform the SVD of $A=U\Sigma V^T$ and notice that
$$
L(X,Y)=\|A-XY\|_2^2=\|U^T(A-XY)V\|_2^2=\|\Sigma-\underbrace{U^TX}_{\tilde X}\underbrace{YV}_{\tilde Y}\|_2^2=\tilde L(\tilde X,\tilde Y).
$$
Since the relations $X\leftrightarrow\tilde X$, $Y\leftrightarrow\tilde Y$ are linear, the convexity of $L$ is equivalent to that of $\tilde L$.

Now take
$$
\tilde X=\left[\matrix{x & 0\\0 & 0}\right],\quad \tilde Y=\left[\matrix{-y & 0\\0 & 0}\right],\qquad x,y\ge 0.
$$
Then
$$
\tilde L(\tilde X,\tilde Y)=\left\|\left[\matrix{\sigma_1+xy & &\\&\sigma_2 &\\&&\ddots}\right]\right\|_2^2=
(\sigma_1+xy)^2=f(x,y).
$$
The function $f(x,y)$ is not convex for $x,y\ge 0$ because its Hessian is indefinite there:
$$
\nabla f(x,y)=2(\sigma_1+xy)\left[\matrix{y\\x}\right],\qquad
\nabla^2 f(x,y)=2\left[\matrix{y^2 & \sigma_1+2xy\\\sigma_1+2xy & x^2}\right]
$$
and 
$$
\det\nabla^2 f(x,y)=4[x^2y^2-(\sigma_1+2xy)^2]=-4(\sigma_1+3xy)(\sigma_1+xy)<0,\quad x,y\ge 0.
$$
Thus $\tilde L$, and hence $L$, is not convex.