# Incomplete proof of Eckart-Young theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Let $$A=U\Sigma V^\top=\sum_i \sigma_i u_i v_i^\top ,$$ be the SVD of a real
matrix $A$ of rank $r$.  We want to show that the matrix $X_k$ of rank $k < r$
that minimises $\lVert A - X_k\rVert_F$ is $$A^k=\sum_i^k \sigma_i u_i
v_i^\top .$$

The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart.E2.80.93Young.E2.80.93Mirsky_theorem_.28for_Frobenius_norm.29) that can be found on the Wikipedia (also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1055616/48134)) is as follows:

> Since $||A-X_k||_F = ||U\Sigma V^\intercal - X_k||_F = ||\Sigma - U^\intercal X_k V ||_F$, denoting $N = U^\intercal X_k V$, an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $k$, a direct calculation gives
>   \begin{equation}
>   ||\Sigma-N||_F^2 = \sum_{i,j} |\Sigma_{i,j} - N_{i,j}|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^r |\sigma_i-N_{ii}|^2+\sum_{i>r}|N_{ii}|^2+\sum_{i\neq j} |N_{i,j}|^2
>  \end{equation}
>   which is minimal when all the non diagonal terms of $N$ equal to zero, and
>   so are all  diagonal terms with $i > r$. Obviously, the minimum of the terms
>   left is attained when $N_{ii} = \sigma_i$ for $i = 1,2,\cdots,k$ and all
>   other $N_{ii}$ are zero.

My understanding of this is that geometrically $\lVert A - X_k\rVert_F$ is the sum of the
distances between a set of orthogonal vectors which form the columns of
$\Sigma$ and another set of vectors which form the columns of N.  In
addition, we know that $n-r$ vectors in the first set are zero, and $n-k$
vectors in the second set must be linearly dependent.

What I don't see is the second part of the proof, namely that it's "obvious"
that $N$ must be chosen to be diagonal, in other words that the columns of $N$ must point in the same directions as the columns of $\Sigma$.  Intuitively, it does seem that the optimal $N$ must be diagonal, but it's not obvious to me. I'd appreciate if somebody could clarify this point?

Comment: FYI, here's complete proof; https://math.stackexchange.com/a/759174/126357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three terms on the right hand side, each involving different elements of the $N$ matrix, and each a sum of squares.  Since the right hand side is separable, you can minimize each of the three terms separately.

Is it clear to you that

$\min \sum_{i=1}^{r} | \sigma_{i}-N_{i,i} |^2$

is achieved with $N_{i,i}=\sigma_{i}, i=1, 2, \ldots, r$?

Is it clear to you that

$\min \sum_{i>r} | N_{i,i} |^{2}$

is achieved by setting $N_{i,i}=0, i=r+1, \ldots$?

Is it clear to you that

$\min \sum_{i \neq j} | N_{i,j} |^{2}$

is achieved by setting $N_{i,j}=0, i \neq j$?

Comment: Yes, but the terms are not independent are they? Since $\sum_j\sum_i N_{i,j}^2$ is fixed for a given matrix $X_k$. So it's not clear to me that you can minimise each of the terms separately.

Comment: In each case you've picked values of $N_{i,j}$ that result in the unconstrained minimimum, and this solution also happens to satisfy the constraint, so you're all set.  It's as if I asked you to minimize $x^{2}$ subject to $0 \leq x \leq 1$.  $x=0$ is the unconstrained minimum of $x^{2}$ and satisfies $0 \leq x \leq 1$, so it is also the constrained minimum.

Comment: I don't think this is right. If your answer is correct, the right-hand side becomes zero. However, the left-hand side is strictly larger than zero since it attempts to approximate rank $r$ matrix with rank $k(<r)$.