# Characterization of singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and its singular values be denoted by $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \ldots \sigma_n \geq 0$. Then 
$$ \sigma_i(A) = \min\{\|B \|_2\colon B \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}, \mathrm{rank}(A-B) \leq i-1 \}. $$
How is this characterization of singular values obtained, is there a reference about it?

Comment: This is a consequence of the [Eckart-Young theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_spectral_norm)).  I'm not sure where to find a better reference for this fact, but I think "Topics in Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson would be a good bet.

Comment: I find the second proof [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/759174/81360) particularly nice

Comment: Does that answer your question sufficiently, or did you want a more thorough explanation?

Comment: Clear, thanks for the reference! I got it through the first proof (optimality of the best rank-$i$ approximation by truncation of the SVD).