# Find $\text{min}{F_{D}(X)}$ for an arbitrary diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, svd

Let $\mathbf{D}$ be a diagonal matrix of size $n\times n$ defined over a field $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbf{X}$ be a matrix of $n \times n$ for which $\text{rank}(\mathbf{X}) = 1$.

Let $$F_\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{X}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{ n}\sum_{j = 1}^{ n}(d_{ij} -x_{ij})^2$$
Find $\min{F_\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{X})}$ for an arbitrary diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$.

**Attempt**

By [Eckart–Young–Mirsky](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759032/proof-of-eckart-young-mirsky-theorem) theorem, the best low-rank approximation in terms of Frobenius' norm can be obtained by a singular value decomposition (as if $F_\mathbf{D}{(\mathbf{X} )}$ is in fact a Frobenius' norm $\mid \mathbf{D}-\mathbf{X} \mid$). SVD of a diagonal matrix is the same matrix with its entries sorted in descending order, which is multiplied by permutation matrices.

If this is the case, then the best rank-one approximation is simply the matrix where all the elements except for the largest one are zeroed out. Hence, $\text{min}\space F$ is a sum of squares of $n - 1$ smallest diagonal entries.

1. Is this correct?
2. Is there a proof that does not rely on SVD? This concept is outside the scope of the exam program.

Comment: Yes you're right; just keep in mind that the entry that we do not zero out is the largest **in magnitude**. As for an alternative approach, I'm not sure. Are there any theorems that we can use from the program that might be applicable here?

Comment: We could prove the EYM theorem (and hence this result) using the Weyl inequalities, for instance

Comment: Maybe there's a way to take advantage of the fact that we're only talking about rank-1 matrices

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, about **in magnitude** -- I forgot to mention it. I suppose the answer will still be accepted despite the theorem not being mentioned in the programme, so any of the proposed methods would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch of Proof:** For any unit vector $\mathbf u$, we can consider the rank-1 matrices $\mathbf X$ whose column space is spanned by $\mathbf u$. Verify that among these matrices, the matrix that minimizes $F_{\mathbf D}(\mathbf X)$ is $\mathbf u \mathbf u ^T\mathbf D$ (you might want to make use of the fact that the projection $\mathbf  u \mathbf  u^T \mathbf  x$ minimizes $\|\mathbf  u - \mathbf  x\|^2$). Now, to find the rank-1 matrix $\mathbf X$ that minimizes $F_{\mathbf D}(\mathbf X)$, it suffices to compute
$$
\min_{\|\mathbf u\| = 1} F_{\mathbf D}(\mathbf u \mathbf u^T\mathbf D) = \|\mathbf D\|_F^2 - \mathbf u^T \mathbf D^2 \mathbf  u.
$$
That is, we must maximize $\mathbf u^T \mathbf D^2 \mathbf  u$. Verify that if $j = \arg \max_{i} |d_i|$, then this maximum is attained with $\mathbf  u  = \mathbf  e_j$, the $j$th standard basis vector (i.e. the $j$th column of the identity matrix).